# Shopify app keep rejecting for security concern

Tags: next.js, shopify, content-security-policy, shopify-app

I am getting the same error again and again from shopify, I tried multiple solutions and did some google work also but can't find the exact solution.

embedded app with Next.js
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code top of  your core files. for security header

```
Header('Content-Security-Policy', 'frame-ancestors ${shop} https://admin.shopify.com;');
```